# вывод гугл мап на jsp странице

Tags: javascript, java-ee, jsp

Необходимо разместить гугл карту на jsp странице в мавен проекте с использованием js.
Пробовал такой вариант:

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" language="java" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html">
  <title>GoogleMap</title>
    <script>
        function initMap() {
            var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 4,
                center: uluru
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: uluru,
                map: map
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAk40H0NzyY7u9TyOwrPUju2aY1F6a8pvA&callback=initMap"></script>

</head>
<body>    
<h2>Google script</h2>
<div id="map" style="height:90%; margin:0px; padding:0px;"></div>
<br />
<img src="resources/ok.png">
</body>
</html>
```

пробовал подключать скрипт с ключем и без ключа и все равно карта не отображается, пробовал в функции function initMap() { прописывать alert("test") то при загрузке страницы алерт появляется.
Кажется что ошибка в скприпте подключения апишки

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAk40H0NzyY7u9TyOwrPUju2aY1F6a8pvA&callback=initMap"></script>
```

хотя он взят с офф документации.

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: а пробовали js код размещать в конце body. вероятно на момент выполнения скрипта, js еще не знает про <div id="map">
Ошибка какая-то или что выводит в консоли?

Comment: да пробовал не помогло. и ошибок не выводи и в консоли пусто

Comment: консоль совсем не пустая. http://prnt.sc/f3ry0e

Comment: у вас она не пуста из-за того, что ключ не правильный key=ключ, попробуйте так key=AIzaSyAk40H0NzyY7u9TyOwrPUju2aY1F6a8pvA

Comment: немного похоже на правду?
http://prnt.sc/f3s1ji

Comment: да должно быть так. но у меня в консоле пусто либо я ей не умею пользоваться.

Comment: ща скину мой вариант, а вы можете подумать что не так у вас) Консоль: открываете страницу в браузере и F12(Chrome) в остальных браузерах не помню.

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой вариант, переместил Ваш js-код в конец body

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" language="java" %> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html">
    <title>GoogleMap</title>

</head>
<body>
<h2>Google script</h2>
<div id="map" style="height:90%; margin:0px; padding:0px;"></div>
<br />
<img src="resources/ok.png">
<script>
    function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 4,
            center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: uluru,
            map: map
        });
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAk40H0NzyY7u9TyOwrPUju2aY1F6a8pvA&callback=initMap"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: все разметил как у вас. все данные грузятся, даже алерт срабатывает но карта не грузится.
[http://prntscr.com/f3sic8]
В консоле появилось такое:
[http://prntscr.com/f3sjqm]

Comment: очень странно, у меня карту подгружает...консоль что говорит?

Comment: [prntscr.com/f3sic8] (prntscr.com/f3sic8) 
prntscr.com/f3sjqm

Comment: а если попробовать не через java запускать этот код, а отдельно, в браузере, то работает? имею ввиду создать левый файл html скопировать туда код и запустить

Comment: нет не работает 
http://prntscr.com/f3sqwk

Comment: <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" language="java" %> эту строку оставить нужно

Comment: На другом компе html файл работает и даже под javой работает. Что с компом может быть?

Comment: не знаю что произошло но карта в html файле заработала. в вот из под  java нет. Может нужно в Intellij IDEA что нибудь настраивать?

Comment: Если на другом компе все работает, напрашивается вывод что что-то не так с вашими настройками. Браузер одинаковый? Попробуйте jdk обновить на всякий

Comment: на ноуте где не работает карта из под javы то она работает из под html файла
а на другом компе карта работает и из под html и из под javы.
браузеры одинаковые отличие только в том что на ноуте проект maven, а на компе обычный java ee проект.

Comment: с мавеном я не знаком, поэтому тут уже не смогу помочь. JS работает - это хорошо)